# Using HTML attribute as a MySQL variable

Tags: html, mysql

I was curious as to whether you can use an HTML attribute as an SQL query variable.

For example:

```
<div class="btn" id="foo" bar="baz">
    <? 
        $bar = **something goes here**;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = '$bar' ORDER BY barname ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    ?>
</div>
```

So `$bar` would be equal to the value of the `bar` attribute of the `<div>` tag. Is this possible? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: do you mean using jquery/javascript to change the attribute? If yes, you need ajax to call the php script dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
<?
$bar = '**something goes here**';
?>
<div class="btn" id="foo" bar="<?=$bar?>">
    <? 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = '$bar' ORDER BY barname ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Preferably I want the variable to be defined in the HTML, as I will be changing it on load depending on the user's default preference

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use buffering to capture the output of your PHP program while it is running, to parse the partial HTML document you get out of it, and then extract the attribute value from it… but that would be insanely complicated.

**This way lies madness. Skip to the next section for a sane approach to the problem.**

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Experiments in output buffering</title>
<div class="btn" id="foo" bar="baz">

<?php
$doc = ob_get_contents();
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($doc);
$div = $dom->getElementById('foo');
$bar = $div->attributes->getNamedItem('bar')->value;
echo "The value of \$bar is $bar";
?>

</div>
```

---

If you want to use a piece of data in multiple places, then store it in a variable (or constant) and then use it in multiple places.

```
<?php
    $bar = get_user_preference();
?>
<div class="btn" id="foo" bar="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($bar); ?>">
<?php
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = ? ORDER BY barname ASC');
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$bar);
    $stmt->execute();
?>
</div>
```